# Determine behaviour of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}z^n$ for $|z|=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, power-series

I am trying to analyze behaviour of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}z^n$ at the set $\{|z| \leq R\}$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence of the series.

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$, then this power series converges for $|z|<1$. I don't know what to do if $|z|=1$. For example, if $z=1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges but if $z=-1$, then $\sum_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges by the alternating test. If $|z|=1$, then $z=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, so we have the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i\theta})^n}{n}$$

I would appreciate any suggestions to help to determine convergence for the general case $|z|=1$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title is confusing. I think you know the radius is 1. You want to know what happens on the unit circle. Please edit.

Comment: you should prove the [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), the Dirichlet test then follows easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use [Dirichlet's test of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) here:
$$ n \to \frac1n,\qquad n=1,2,3\ldots,$$ is decreasing to $0$ and, for $e^{i\theta}\neq 1$ , one gets
$$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik\theta}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{i\theta}\left(1-e^{in\theta} \right)}{1-e^{i\theta} }\right|\leq \frac{2}{|1-e^{i\theta}|}.$$